# True Type fonts. Problems with glyf table

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

I'm trying to learn how to read an open type font file.

The thing is I am having problems reading some tables. I thought it would be enough with the information given at http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm

When trying to read the glyf table I find under simple glyph description 
`flags[n]`, where n is the number of flags.

The problem is I don't know where to get the number of flags from, and without the number of flags reading the table doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my questions, endPtsOfContours had the position of the last point of every contour in the list of coordinates.

I used TTFDUMP to find out what the answer was.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify how the number of flags is computed. The number of flags, `n`, is the *last* element in the `endPtsOfContours` + 1.

Comment: Found at least two fonts for which the formula does not hold true: Bradley Hand ITC Regular and Rage Italic. TTFDUMP returns a different number of flags.

Comment: @IgorBrejc ok, what glyph is showing this problem. What is the actual number of flags? And what is reported in the last element of endPtsOfContours? See https://github.com/vidstige/NRasterizer for small implementation in C# if you need to inspect individual bytes. Can you also link the font files here in a comment?

Comment: @IgorBrejc Please see my answer below. The two mentioned fonts may be using the *Repeat* flag, which can cause a difference between number of flags and number of points.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question I feel that I need add some more information to this topic as the answers above may produce wrong results.

The number of points in a glyph equals the last `endPtsOfContours` + 1. Usually this equals number of flags `n`, but not necessarily. Bit 3 in a flag (the *Repeat* flag) is used indicate that the same flag is repeated several times. If this flag is set, the number of flags can be be lower than the number of points.

The truth is, before reading the flags you cannot know how many bytes you will have to read. You will have to keep reading the flags until you reach the number of points. Here is a small Javascript snipplet that shows how reading the flags could be implemented.

```
var pointCount; // This has to the set to the last endPtsOfContours + 1 
var flags = []; // our internal array of flags
while (flags.length < pointCount) {  
    var flag = fontReader.readByte(); // flag is a single byte
    flags.push(flag); // add flag
    if (flag & 8) {  // if bit 3 is set
        var repeats = fontReader.readByte(); // next byte indicates repeats of the flag
        for (; repeats > 0; repeats--) {
            flags.push(flag); // add same flag again
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot tell you if or how often the *Repeat* flag is used in real world fonts (probably the two fonts Bradley Hand ITC Regular and Rage Italic mentioned in the comments above use it), but if you want to make sure that you read the correct number of flags, you will have to take that bit it into account.

Comment: Nice! How did you find this out? Any source? I read the specs (a long time ago) without fining anything :-/

Comment: @vistige I took this from the Open Type Spec at https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm
It's in the *flags* table (bit 3 is the important one)..